# Remove other class from section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website full of divs. In this `div` there are two elements YES and NO with the same class named `foo`. Now when the site loads, a outsource script adds randomly the class `faa` to one of the element YES or NO.
Now i have set a `onclick` event on the class `foo`.

As soon as somebody clicks on YES or NO, i want to add the class `faa` to that element and remove it from the other (if necessary. i mean he could click on the element which already has this class).

I know how to add a class to the clicked one. Just simply:

```
$(this).addClass('foo');
```

but how do I remove the class first from the other element?

**Edit**:

I think i described it not very well.

So here is an example of my HTML strucutre:

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="foo">YES</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo faa">NO</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="foo">YES</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo">NO</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="foo faa">YES</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo">NO</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="foo">YES</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo">NO</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="foo faa">YES</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo">NO</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="foo">YES</a>
    <a href="#" class="foo faa">NO</a>
</div>
```

So if somebody clicks on the first YES, the class `faa` should be only removed from the one in the first div and not from all of them.

Comment: can you provide the html structure ?

Comment: So you know about `.addClass()` but don't know about `.removeClass()`?

Comment: please share html for div's?

Comment: since both your elements (yes/no) have the class "foo" you can use that class name to remove class "faa" from both (even if only one of them has the class) => $("foo").removeClass("faa")

Comment: You should always post HTML code to avoid confusions while answering such questions.

Comment: Please take a look at my post again.

Comment: Please refrain from commenting all answers to solicit reviews. Peers willing to review will notice your edit and act accordingly without you spamming.

Comment: please have a look at answer updated by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No share 2 things : same parent + same class (foo)

So you can use these 2 criterias to select both of them and remove the "faa" class

```
    //this refers to the clicked answer (either Yes or No)
    //=> this.parent() refers to the div with class='box'
    // => $(this).parent().find('.foo') refers to both answers Yes and No
    //we can simply remove the faa class
    $(this).parent().find(".foo").removeClass("faa")
```

Comment: Please take a look at my post again.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
$(this).removeClass('foo');
```

Comment: Please take a look at my post again.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

edit after question update :

```
//remove "faa" class to all children of "this"'s parent with box class :
$(this).closest('.box').find('.faa').removeClass('faa');
```

Comment: add / remove class is `faa` and not `foo`.

Comment: Please take a look at my post again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : On click event of `foo`, remove `faa` class its sibling `foo` element and then add class `faa` to clicked `foo` div as shown below

```
$(function(){
  $('.foo').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).siblings('.foo').removeClass('faa');
     $(this).addClass('faa');
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo for add / remove class](http://jsfiddle.net/xg2jsk3t/)**

More Information on **[siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**

Comment: Please take a look at my post again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to remove the class `faa` from the siblings of the clicked element. Then you'll want to add the class `faa` to the clicked element.

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('faa');
  $(this).addClass('faa');
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc04r6nw/)